# How to remove some warning messages using Django and Python

Tags: python, django

I need some help. I am getting some warning messages while formatting my code using `pylint`. I am explaining those warning messages below.

```
C: 77, 0: Line too long (82/80) (line-too-long)
C:125, 0: Line too long (83/80) (line-too-long)
E: 76,13: Class 'Service' has no 'objects' member (no-member)
E:106,19: Class 'Personal' has no 'objects' member (no-member)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
def view_service(request):
    """ This function helps to display the past booking items"""

    people = Service.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'bookingservice/view_service.html', {'people': people})
```

> models.py:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    """In this class the columns for service table has declared"""
    cname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_service = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    vechile_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    service_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Personal(models.Model):
    """In this class the columns for Person table has declared"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    driving_license = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

In the above function last line is showing `too long` and another warning related to `Service` class is also there. Here I need to remove both of the warning messages. Please help.

Comment: Please check my updated post.

Answer (score 1):

`E: 76,13: Class 'Service' has no 'objects' member (no-member)` is Django specific. pylint doesn't understand Django. You need to use a different tool or add [pylint-django](https://blog.landscape.io/using-pylint-on-django-projects-with-pylint-django.html) or a similar plugin to make pylint understand Django.

The `C` errors are simply lines that are longer than pylint's standard line length. I can't tell what line 125 is, but 77 appears to be referring to:

`return render(request, 'bookingservice/view_service.html', {'people': people})`

One of the neat things I've learned about Python is that if you have an open parenthetical expression then you can span lines without extra code:

`return render(request, 'bookingservice/view_service.html',
                   {'people': people})`